# Should we use Salesforce lightning design system?

Tags: slds

One of our components got distorted due to Spring 23 because of an upgrade did by Lightning Design System. In Visualforce world, it is a general recommendation not to use Salesforce built in CSS. Should we use Salesforce lightning design system or use our own css?

Comment: Yes if you want to leverage the ready made `lighting-` components and get these benefits https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/ (scroll down).

Comment: You can use your own CSS but you can then expect your components to not feel like they fit with the rest of the UI.